# how to delete huge mysql rows depending on not equal

Tags: mysql

the problem that its a huge amount the query would be like

```
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `membership` = 'C' AND (`id` != '1' AND `id` !='2' AND ...... thousands of ids );
```

how I can do that ?

I did also WHERE `id` NOT IN ("1","2"); but also did not work

can I use loop or something like that

the IDs that I want to keep and do not delete comes from another table contains a field holds the user ID that I don't want to delete I used PHP script to help me to generate the SQL query

like

```
<?php
require_once("inc.php");
$realty_uids = $db->query("SELECT `uid` from `realty2` ORDER BY `uid`");

$r = $db->fetch_assoc($realty_uids);



while($r = $db->fetch_assoc($realty_uids)){
    $array[] = $r['uid'];
}
$input = array_unique($array);

echo "DELETE from `members` WHERE `membership` = 'C' ";
foreach($input as $key => $value){

    echo " AND `id` != '".$value."' <br>";

}
echo ";";
```

Comment: Define "did not work." Also why use strings for integers, or why use IN for a single value?

Comment: Where do the IDs come from? You can use a subquery to feed the IDs to the delete clause. Or use a JOIN with delete. If the list of IDs comes from somewhere else you may consider using a text editor to do some string manipulation to generate the 'IN ( ... )' statement

Comment: Can you provide more context? You obviously know which id's you don't want to delete, how did you establish that? can you not base the query on that instead?

Comment: Okay the IDs comes from another table that contains a column that have the member ID who inserted that row .. I collected the ids using PHP to generate the SQL query to a web page as a text then i copied it to phpMyadmin to run it in SQL tab but the SQL query was huge and freezing my PC

Comment: also I'll Edit my post to explain more

Comment: It is not an efficient way to execute a query, are you tried make directly a subquery with `NOT EXISTS` sentence?

Comment: how I can use this way NOT EXISTS

Comment: hello @Origin  also I would like to ask how I can use JOIN with that query as the IDs in another table

Comment: You can make something like `DELETE FROM members m WHERE m.membership = 'C' and NOT EXISTS (SELECT at.id FROM another_table at WHERE at.id = m.id);`

Comment: `DELETE m FROM members m LEFT JOIN another_table at ON at.id = m.id WHERE at.id IS NULL;` would be functionally equivalent to the query from @amaia, though one form might be faster than the other depending on how the optimizer handles them.  Some people find this style counterintuitive, since `WHERE at.id IS NULL` doesn't refer to the actual rows in another_table, but instead refers to the `NULL`s in the projection, where this column is null for rows in `m` for which the left join did not find a match in `at`.

Comment: Be sure your data is backed up if you're trying either query against your live database.  It's easy to make a logical error and delete something that you didn't intend.

Comment: `DELETE FROM members m WHERE m.membership = 'C' AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT at.uid FROM realty2 at WHERE at.uid = m.id);` this did not work as it says  **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm WHERE m.membership = 'C' AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT at.uid FROM `realty2` at WHERE ' at line 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `members` WHERE `membership` = 'C' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT at.uid FROM `realty2` at WHERE at.uid = `members`.id);
```

This way worked good thanks for every one tried :)